# Не переведено уведомление о неактивности

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Как воспроизвести - не знаю.

[image: Instant updates have been disabled due to inactivity обновить to reconnect]

Обращаю внимание, что строка на картинке склеивается из нескольких строк:

- [Instant updates have been disabled due to inactivity](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/101190790?key=6866ffbd9f866796c2c5dc100f204b6b)
- [refresh](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263339?key=03b62516184fb6ef591f45bd4974b753)
- [to reconnect](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/101190791?key=f1d49422f82f52d084577a303e8c928d)

Так что переводить нужно каждую строку отдельно с учетом их последующего склеивания.

Comment: Предлагайте варианты - строку в транзифексе вижу, можно будет легко перевести.

Comment: @alexolut, пойдёт?

Comment: я думаю, лучше вынести как ответ и решить голосованием.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Подгрузка обновлений на странице была приостановлена из-за вашего бездействия.
2. > Обновите страницу
3. > для возобновления подгрузки.

Да, ссылкой является вся фраза «Обновите страницу».

Вот только не знаю, что делать с тавтологией («подгрузка» — «для возобновления подгрузки», «обновлений» — «обновите»).

Comment: Не получится ли слишком длинно, так, что на мелких экранах не будет видна фраза целиком?

Answer (score 0):

**Возможный перевод:**

> Уведомления отключены из-за неактивности.

---

> Обновить

---

> Для возобновления

Comment: С прописными буквами и точкой не пойдет при склеивании. Т.е. как минимум `д` надо сделать строчной.

Comment: Тут, кстати, всплывает другая проблема. В том, что фактически тут два предложения, но в английской версии разделения почему-то нет.

Comment: @alexolut, вот тут из возникает плохое продумывание архитектуры. Мало того, что логически одну фразу зачем-то разбили на 3 части, так ещё и не подумали что в других языках это разбиение может сослужить плохую службу.

Answer (score 0):

Компиляция уже данных ответов

1. `Мгновенные уведомления отключены из-за неактивности.`
2. `Обновите страницу`
3. `для переподключения.`

Если же нету возможность изменить строчку `"обновить"` (она же наверняка где-то ещё используется), тогда, возможно, следующая комбинация лучше

1. `Мгновенные уведомления отключены из-за неактивности. Нужно`
2. `обновить`
3. `страницу для переподключения.`